# POST, PUT - Проблемы с UTF-8

Tags: java, utf-8, rest

Запросы POST и PUT просят UTF-8. Сервер выдаёт

> 400 Bad Request
>   Invalid UTF-8 middle byte 0xee

Перепробовал кучу вариантов и не один не подошёл.

Например код из сервиса:

```
@POST 
@Path("/add")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response addNote(Note note){
    nList.add(note);
    return Response.status(201).build();
```

Сам запрос подаю через cURL.
Пробовал такие варианты:

> curl -X POST -i -H "Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8" -d
>   "{\"title\":\"новая заметка\"}"
>   http://localhost:8080/test_war_exploded/notes/add
>
> curl -H "Accept: application/json; charset=utf-8" -X POST -i -H "Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8" -d
>   "{\"title\":\"новая заметка\"}"
>   http://localhost:8080/test_war_exploded/notes/add
>
> curl -X POST -i -H "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8" -d
>   "{\"title\":\"новая заметка\"}"
>   http://localhost:8080/test_war_exploded/notes/add

В код добавлял:

```
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON + ";charset=utf-8")
```

Пробовал:

```
return Response.status(201).header("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8").build();
```

Где же засада?

Comment: Операционная система, из под которой выполняется curl, какая?

Comment: Sergey Gornostaev win7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если вы запускаете curl в cmd, то параметр аргумента `-d` имеет ту же кодировку, что и консоль Windows - CP866. Обойти это можно сохранив json в файл в кодировке utf-8 и передавая тело запроса так:

```
curl -X POST -i -H "Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8" -d @C:\request_body.json
```

Comment: Два вопроса 1.Каким образом сохраняется мой json в C:\request_body.json?
2.если такие премудрости с cURL, как ещё возможно посылать запросы для проверки сервиса?

Comment: Просто создаёте новый текстовый файл с именем request_body.json, записываете в него `{"title": "новая заметка"}`, сохраняете и указываете в параметр curl. Вместо curl можно использовать что-нибудь типа Postman, но мне лично такие софтины никогда не нравились.

Comment: Да, файл создать догадался. Но делу это не помогло. По-прежнему **Invalid UTF-8 middle byte 0xee**. Опять же если в файле писать всё на латинице, то ошибок нет, всё работает. А из под линукса cURL по умолчанию работает с utf?

Comment: Значит у вас файл не в utf-8 кодировке. В большинстве современных Linux'ов консоль использует utf-8 кодировку, соответственно и параметры в curl передаются в ней же.

Comment: Точно так и было. Т.е. методика должна быть такой:
1.Я создаю массив из объектов
2.Сохраняю этот массив в файл json в кодировке utf-8(опять же как это сделать, но это уже другой вопрос)
3.Делаю запросы с учётом файла.